# How to make exceptions in a copy of a row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm beginner at Macros I need to do a copy of rows but I have to exclude some columns. EntireRow is working but I need to exclude the columns I,G,H

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim RngToChk as Range, RngToPaste as Range
    Set RngToCheck=Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter range", Type:=8)
    Dim strtofind as String
    Inttofind=InputBox("Give your Indicator")
    Dim i as long
    For i = RngToChk.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If RngToChk(i).value=strtofind Then
            RngToCheck(i).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Set RngToPaste=RngToChk(i).Offset(1)
            RngToPaste.EntireRow.Value=RngToChk(i).EntireRow.Value
            RngToPaste.EntireRow.Font.Color=RGB(255,0,0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not copy the whole row and then delete those columns?

Comment: Indenting your code and spacing it out a little makes it much more readable.

Comment: ^ [Check out this cool indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) :)

Comment: And do you actually need the whole row? All 16k columns or however many it is?

Comment: I have 200 columns and 15000 rows, I need to exclude of the copy that columns because I need to show the differences

Comment: Just an FYI.  Might want to change in `For i = RngToChk.Rows.Coumt To 1 Step -1` to  `For i = RngToChk.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your module:

```
Function AlmostEntireRow(StartingPoint As Range) As Range
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Row = StartingPoint.Row
    Set TargetSheet = StartingPoint.Worksheet
    Set AlmostEntireRow = Union(TargetSheet.Range("A" & Row & ":F" & Row), TargetSheet.Range("J" & Row & ":GR" & Row))
End Function
```

When you are using it, replace

```
RngToPaste.EntireRow.Font.Color=RGB(255,0,0)
```

with

```
AlmostEntireRow(RngToPaste).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

and so on.

The function builds a range from the input range, consisting of columns A to F and J to GR. Adjust as needed.

**Update**
The suggested method does not work when copying rows. Here is a copy method as well.

```
Sub CopyAlmostEntireRow(FromRow As Range, ToRow As Range)
    Dim FromRange As Range
    Dim ToRange As Range

    Set FromRange = FromRow.Worksheet.Range("A" & FromRow.Row & ":F" & FromRow.Row)
    Set ToRange = ToRow.Worksheet.Range("A" & ToRow.Row & ":F" & ToRow.Row)
    ToRange.Value = FromRange.Value

    Set FromRange = FromRow.Worksheet.Range("J" & FromRow.Row & ":GR" & FromRow.Row)
    Set ToRange = ToRow.Worksheet.Range("J" & ToRow.Row & ":GR" & ToRow.Row)
    ToRange.Value = FromRange.Value

End Sub

' Call with something like this:
CopyAlmostEntireRow RngToChk(i), RngToPaste
```

Comment: Is almost the solution but in column J is copyong the value of A1 below the information.

Comment: How I can call It?

Comment: The last row is an example of how to call it